# variable +=% possible or how to get the next interval of a number after another number

Tags: python, math, range, modulo

I want to be able to do something like the following...

Say I want a list of every number from 100-500 that is a multiple of 33.

```
>>> a = 100
>>> b = 500
>>> range(a,b,33)
[100, 133, 166, 199, 232, 265, 298, 331, 364, 397, 430, 463, 496]
```

This is not what I want, this is because `a` is not a multiple of 33.

To get the next multiple of 33 from `a` I can do:

```
a = a - a % 33 + 33
```

I want to know if there is an easier way to do this so that if I want to create this range without knowing the actual values and without having to define them beforehand..

Such as:

```
>>> def multiple(a, b, c):
    return range(a+=%c, b, c) #if this was possible
```

And obviously it would return me a range which would be correct, for example:

```
>>> multiple(100, 500, 33)
[132, 165, 198, 231, 264, 297, 330, 363, 396, 429, 462, 495]
```

I am aware I can do something simple like:

```
range(a - a%c + c, b, c)
```

However, without getting into details, calling the value of `a` is expensive for me in my case, and I would like to be able to find a way to not have to call it a second time, and also the above method is really not nice looking at all.

I really was not sure what the title of my question should be, but I suppose what I am looking for is a way to find the next multiple of a number after another given number.

Thank you.

Comment: What should be the result of `multiple(66, 132, 33)`?

Comment: @NPE nice question, It should be [66, 99, 132]

Comment: why not simply store a in a variable so you can use it twice w/o loading it twice?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following does what you want and only uses `a` once:

```py
In [4]: range((a + c - 1) // c * c, b + 1, c)
Out[4]: [132, 165, 198, 231, 264, 297, 330, 363, 396, 429, 462, 495]
```

I would still place it into a helper function, rendering moot the question of how many times `a` is used.

Unlike the code in your question, this actually works correctly for cases when `a` is evenly divisible by `c`. Also, unlike the code in your question, it includes `b` in the range (as it should, according to your answer to my question in the comments):

```py
In [15]: range((a + c - 1) // c * c, b + 1, c)
Out[15]: [66, 99, 132]
```

Comment: this seems also quite wasteful. could you explain to me what exactly is going on here?

Comment: @InbarRose: If I were in your shoes, I'd focus on correctness first and on performance second. There are at least two bugs in the `range()` call in your question. That said, when I time my solution on a=100 b=500 c=33, it takes under 800ns. Are you saying that's not fast enough for your needs?

Comment: Thank you NPE. you have helped me with the problem, as well as understanding what it is exactly I was actually looking for in the first place. with the knowledge brought on by hindsight, I would have asked a completely different question. You managed to answer it nonetheless, good job, thanks again. (and to more directly answer your question, my code now simply uses a helper function that gets a,b,c and uses your range suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Well, to get the multiple of `33` everytime, you would need to start with a `multiple of 33` only.

So, start with first multiple of `33` after `100`, because `range` function will just keep on adding `33` to get next multiples.

To get the first multiple of `33` after a number `num`, you can use: -

```
num / 33 * 33 + 33  <==>  (num / 33 + 1) * 33
```

So, for your range you can use: -

```
>>> a = 100
>>> b = 500
>>> a = (a / 33 + 1) * 33
>>> range(a, b, 33)
[132, 165, 198, 231, 264, 297, 330, 363, 396, 429, 462, 495]
```